# "Featured Image" or "Thumbnail" in Wordpress 3?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, wordpress-featured-image

What's the difference between a featured image and thumbnail, and why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's the difference between a featured image and thumbnail...?

The name! 'Featured images' in 3.0 are what 'post thumbnails' were in 2.9.

The code is the same, but from a user experience angle, I think they decided that 'post thumbnail' was a little ambiguous and/or confusing.